# MATLAB- How to plot a single "packed" variable

Tags: matlab

so in MATLAB, when using ODE45 for multiple ODEs, you can "pack" as my professor calls it, terms into a single term like so

```
function [dYdt] = HW3_P2_ftn(t,Y)

%Unpack the state variables
D = Y(1);
CA = Y(2);
```

So now Y is made up of two vectors of different variables.

At the end of my code, after ODE45, I want to plot only Y(2) without Y(1).

Can someone explain to me how I may do that?

Answer (score 1):

My fault guys, over complicating it.

Best option is to slice the matrix using

```
CA= Y(:,2);

Plot(t,CA)
```